# C/C++ <sys/socket.h> Using send() in a loop, sending multiple messages

Tags: c++

So what I'm trying to do is a server-client setup where client connects to a server and can send multiple various messages to the server which responds with certain message, depending on what was sent from the client, until message "close" closes the connection.

I got it working (modified an online example) but I'm not sure it's the right way to send multiple messages. The problem is, that in my case I cannot use send() function on a client side in a loop unless:

- the code that creates a socket and connects to a server is in the same loop with send() on a client side, and accept() is in the same loop as read() on the server side, which doesn't seem right.
- the code is before the loop on both sides, but in this case client can't reconnect.

Server:

```
    int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    char *hello = "Hello from server";

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt))) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address)) < 0) {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    // Accept
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t *)&addrlen)) < 0) {
        perror("accept");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (true) {

        // valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024);
        // printf("Buffer: %s\n",buffer );

        // if (recv(new_socket, buffer, 1024, MSG_PEEK) > 0) {
        //     printf("Buffer: %s\n",buffer );
        // }

        if (read(new_socket, buffer, 1024) > 0) {
            printf("Buffer: %s\n", buffer);
        }
        bzero(buffer, 1024);
    }

    send(new_socket, hello, strlen(hello), 0);
    printf("Hello message sent\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Client:

```
    int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) { 
    struct sockaddr_in address; 
    int sock = 0, valread; 
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
    // char *hello = "Hel0o from client"; 
    char *hello; 
    char buffer[1024] = {0}; 

    std::string msg;

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) { 
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form 
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0)  { 
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) { 
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n"); 
        return -1; 
    }

    while (true) {
        std::cout << "msg: ";
        std::cin >> msg;

        hello = new char[msg.length() + 1];
        std::strcpy(hello, msg.c_str());

        send(sock , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 );
    }

    printf("Hello message sent\n"); 
    valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024); 
    printf("%s\n",buffer ); 
    return 0; 
}
```

What would be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Note: TCP does not deal in messages. It is a a stream of data. It is up to you to establish a protocol and place messages that adhere to that protocol in the stream. The recipient must continue reading until the entire message, as defined by the protocol, has been received You cannot simply `printf("Buffer: %s\n", buffer);` because `buffer` may not be a null terminated string. `bzero(buffer, 1024);` tries, but cannot quite do the job. Try reading one byte less to leave room for the null. This staves off disaster, but does not establish a protocol.

Comment: Messages must be framed so the recipient knows where one message ends and the next begins. There are two ways to frame a message in TCP: send the message's length before sending the message's data, or end the message with a unique delimiter that never appears in the message data. The recipient can then read the message length followed by the specified amount of data, or can read until the delimiter is read.

Comment: Okay, but how do I code the server and the client for the client to be able to reconnect? Creating a new socket at client side each time I use send() and accepting new sockets every time I read surely can't be the right way to do it.